# What is insoluble in drinking alcohol, but edible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry, alcohols

What substances are edible for human consumption, but will not mix with alcohol? What is a substance that would block alcohol from mixing with its counterparts in a product?
For example: You make a cupcake and want an alcohol shot in that cupcake. What substance could the alcohol shot be contained in so it wouldn't disperse into the cupcake, but still be edible?

Comment: When you say *edible*, you mean non-poisonous and human-stomach-degradable?

Comment: A sugar hull with a chocolate coating to prevent evaporation does a great job https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praline .

Comment: In a cupcake? So, edible AND able to withstand a cooking process to 180oC??

Comment: AND able to withstand the pressure of alcohol vapour at 180oC.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Ethanol does not dissolve chocolate, which consists mostly of butter and sugar. These mini alcohol filled chocolates are very common party candies. You could try inserting one of these into your cupcakes after you have baked them.

You could also try making a mold for a gelatin-based shot cup, as gelatin is also insoluble in ethanol. Gelatin is capable of absorbing alcohol, however, so I do not recommend making these too far in advance, lest they turn soggy.

Answer (score 2):

In first order approxiamtion: Ethanol and similar substances solvable in water cant be mixed with unpolar substances. You could carry alcohol in a bowl of solid fat for some time.

But to solve your problem of sweet drunkness have a look in a candy shop: You can fill chocolate (made up of fat and sugar primary) with liquor. Liquid alcohol will barely survive head of a stove in same time biscuits need, as well as solid fat.